# How to increase the "background position" content dynamically depending on "X" right (hover)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I need to automatically increase the "background-position" pencil according to the content and that is always right (hover).

```
<!-- INICIO estilos pregunta -->
<div class="preguntayrespuesta"> 
    <div class="pregunta">  
        <h2 style="background-position: 370.796875px 5px;">1. The "background position" of this pencil looks good ... =)</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="delete" ></a>
    <div class="respuesta">
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="S"> Yes <br />
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="N"> No <br />
    </div> 
</div>
<!-- FIN estilos pregunta -->
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/44Rfw/)

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly do you want with the pencil? Where does it need to go? (btw, if you ask if the background-pos is good and you can answer "No", then you don't really need the second question do you?)

Comment: I just need the pen not to be mounted, the pen always is to the right as in the first case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script solution. The idea is create some dummy element to measure the text width of the `h2` element, and then use that width (with some offset) to set the background-position accordingly:

```
var dummy = $('<span>').css({display:'inline-block'}).appendTo('body');                  
$('h2').each(function(i,e){
  dummy.css('font', $(e).css('font'))
     .css('max-width', $(e).width())
     .css('padding', $(e).css('padding'))
     .css('box-sizing', $(e).css('box-sizing'))
     .html($(e).html());    
  $(e).css('background-position', 'right ' + ($(e).width() - dummy.width()) + 'px top 0px');
});
dummy.remove();
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/44Rfw/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Hola Amigo :) you should start by aligning the background to the right(horizontally)...

```
.preguntayrespuesta h2:hover {
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Remove the ugly inline styles you've specified for the `h2`'s, you don't need them..

```
<div class="pregunta">  
    <h2>1. The "background position" of this pencil looks good ... =)</h2>
```

And lastly, make your questions display `inline-block` so that the box wraps nicely around its contents, otherwise the "pencil" will be displayed far beyond to the right of the question. Also, increase the right padding to be a tiny bit wider than the pencil...

```
.preguntayrespuesta h2{
    padding-right: 32px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/44Rfw/2/)

Comment: @JoséMaríaBarrientos this answer is really good, you should accept it. My thought was just that you could not change the `display:block` of the `h2`. If using `display:inline-block` is OK, this would be the solution you need. The uses of `display:inline-block` and `block` in this case differ only when you want to apply some border around your `h2` element, ...

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference, especially because the `h2` has no siblings and it's inside a block element. If he wants to apply styles to the "question" he could style the `h2` or the parent `div`...depending on the styles in question